# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() - some commands working in IDE, but not from an executable .jar file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I exported my Maven Spring Boot project as a .jar file, and everything seems to be working fine, except for a few commands that my app is supposed to run in the Terminal.

For example "shutdown now" will run, and turn off the PC, but "xdg-open somelink.com" doesn't do anything?

I've tried executing the terminal commands in the following two ways:

```
  public void runInTerminal(String cmd){
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", cmd);


        try {

            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(output);
                System.exit(0);
            } else {

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And also tried

```
 public void commandRun(String cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
        pr.waitFor();
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: *...but "xdg-open somelink.com" doesn't do anything?* Your code works for me for that command

Comment: Not a good idea though to ignore non-zero exit and not to process stderr

Comment: @g00se It opens up a webpage in your default browser in Linux terminal, works for me

Comment: @g00se What would be the best way to handle non-zero exit here?

Comment: *@g00se It opens up a webpage in your default browser in Linux terminal, works for me* I'm confused. I know what it does. The point is you said it DOESN'T work for you. I've already quoted what you wrote

Comment: @g00se It doesn't work when executed from a .jar executable file, works only when running in IDE

Comment: Works for me. See http://technojeeves.com/tech/runner.jar. Invoke `java -jar runner.jar 'xdg-open https://technojeeves.com`

Answer (score 0):

Check that `<jre-dir>/lib/jspawnhelper/jspawnhelper` have the `-X flag` (executable) enabled.

`ProcessBuilder` is a wrapper for `Runtime.exec` who is exeucte commands nativly throu the OS. Without the executable-flag on os-level you can not execute commands.